# Aptana, compile SASS remotely

Tags: css, sass, aptana, compass

So I've been using Aptana for quite a while now at work and we've been working remotely and today I had a little job where Sass was involve. I asked the team how Aptana is compiling the Sass remotely but it was all done by scripts behind svn that we're using.

So my question is how can you use aptana to compile Sass file remotely without some genius svn scripts. I want to update some SASS lines on my website which can be done the long way (work locally - compile - re-upload).

I've tried google and no luck so far.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and maybe I am misunderstanding).. But why do you want to make the change directly in SVN or on the server? Wouldn't you want to make the changes local first to ensure that they work correctly before committing them to SVN?

Comment: Oh at work we have our dev branches so it wouldn't affect the live site. I want to do it on my website so it doesn't really matter whether I do it locally or straight from my host as the site is pretty much under dev. I'd say just trying to find other ways making edits easier, I wouldn't do it this way if its for my client(s).